# React.How do I check redux via jest?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

How do I check if redux action is working ?
and at the end of the execution, check dataState for data ?

For example:

To test the function of the authorization in the application.
`expect(AuthMethod(login, password));`

Example:

````
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(AuthLoading());

    try {
      var date = new Date().getDate();
      var month = new Date().getMonth() + 1; 
      var year = new Date().getFullYear();
      var hours = new Date().getHours(); 
      var min = new Date().getMinutes(); 
      var sec = new Date().getSeconds();
      var time =
        date + '-' + month + '-' + year + ' ' + hours + ':' + min + ':' + sec;

      let response = await fetch(
        'http://' + ServerLink + ':' + ServerPort + '/tmo/rest/user',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            login: login,
            password: password,
            deviceSerialNumber: '1111111', 
            currentAppVersion: AppVersion,
            currentDateTime: time,
          }),
        },
      );

      let data = await response.json();
      if (data.sessionToken === '') {
        dispatch(AuthFailure('Token null'));
      } else {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('token', data.sessionToken);
        dispatch(AuthSuccess(data));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(AuthFailure(e.message));
    }
  };
};```
````

Answer (score 0):

can you post an example of your action?

but in the meantime, lets say you have an action like so:

```
export const yourAction = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
    await dispatch({type: 'MY_ACTION_TYPE, payload: [1,2,3] })
}
```

simply test like so:

```
it('should do something', async () => {
   await yourAction(data)(dispatch)
   expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalled() // or
   expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(somethingYouExpectInHere)
})
```